# Unable to download artifactory from search.maven.org

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, jberet

I'm trying to do a *clean install* on this project

https://github.com/jberet/jberet-wildfly-samples

I'm stucked with this error:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   org.jberet.samples:clusterInfinispan:war:1.4.0.Alpha-SNAPSHOT: Failed
>   to collect dependencies at
>   org.jberet:jberet-wildfly-cluster-infinispan:jar:1.3.0.Final: Failed
>   to read artifact descriptor for
>   **org.jberet:jberet-wildfly-cluster-infinispan:jar:1.3.0.Final**: Failure
>   to find org.jberet:jberet-wildfly:pom:1.4.0.Alpha-SNAPSHOT

It appears that artifactory is ONLY available on [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/)

I tried to do either a force update -U and to manually clean the local repo directory, but nothing changes.
I wonder if I have to manually add the above repo or should automatically seek there

Any hints?

Comment: If still facing problem then add the jars manually.

Comment: I've manually downloaded pom, sources, and jar from repo and added manually to local repo, but still having error :(

Comment: You will never find SNAPSHOT's in Maven Central repository only releases.

Answer (score 1):

I think he didn't publish 1.4.0.Alpha in maven center.
You can try to change 1.4.0.Alpha to 1.3.0.Final in pom.xml like this

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.jberet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jberet-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.jberet.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-jberet-samples</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
```

And use `mvn clean install -Pwildfly`

Comment: actually the artifactory is present https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jberet/jberet-parent/1.4.0.Alpha

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you are right: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jberet/jberet-wildfly-cluster-infinispan/1.3.0.Final/jar

I'm not sure if anybody here on Stackoverflow will be able to help you.

Continue your issue with jberet's community: https://github.com/jberet/jberet-wildfly-samples/issues/2 you have to solve it with them.

EDIT:

Now that I think more about it, it's also possible to add their SNAPSHOT repository to your settings.xml file: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories but I didn't find link to their repository.

Anyway: witnessing this I would stay away from jberet project, because this is a big failure on their part.

Answer (score 0):

Read the maven error: "*failure to find org.jberet:jberet-wildfly:pom:1.4.0.Alpha-SNAPSHOT*" means there is a a dependency referencing org.jberet:jberet-wildfly:pom **1.4.0.Alpha-SNAPSHOT**.

- Either the repository forbids deploying SNAPSHOT (and it make sense for central)
- either your configuration forbids downloading SNAPSHOT (see http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories).

You should check local pom.xml referencing 1.4.0.Alpha-SNAPSHOT and replace it with a non SNAPSHOT (1.4.0.Alpha for beginners).

Comment: the SNAPSHOT is the project itself that I'm trying to build, so there should not be any forbid to download a final release even if the parent project is a SNAPSHOT. btw I tried to rename the version to just Apha but nothing changed

Comment: Could be the parent pom of jberet-wildfly-cluster-infinispan is not found.  I'll check and publish it if needed.

Comment: To work around this issue, you can `git clone https://github.com/jberet/jberet-wildfly` into your local workspace and build jberet-wildfly locally to make it available.

Comment: I've released jberet-wildfly-* 1.3.1.Final, and upgrade a few deps versions in jberet-wildfly-samples.  You may want to update your project and try again (the new versions will take a while to sync up to maven central).